# Add a new entity into a table that deletes it in a trigger on insert

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a requirement to insert a record into a table which is used as a queue. In the database, this table has a trigger that copies the new record to another table and deletes the original row. Unfortunately I cannot change the behaviour of the database.   The problem is the entity framework returns a DbUpdateConcurrencyException:

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).
```

Looking at the SQL generated in profiler I believe it's because it's trying to validate that a new row was added, but because the trigger deletes the new row the entity framework thinks 0 rows have been affected...

I've tried setting the  following property with no luck:

```
Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Is there any way to turn off this behaviour in EF6?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I am running into the same issue

Comment: @mep2664 Hmm, can't recall 100%, but I don't think so - I think in the end I  ended up using DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() to run raw sql just for this particular insert. Yuck but didn't have time to find a proper solution.